# Setting transparent background for QWebView

Tags: c++, html, css, qt

I am trying to set transparent background to a `QWebView` element.

```
+---------------------------+
| x | Window title          | <<< Hidden borders and title bar
+---------------------------+     view->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
|                           |
|     ******************    |   
|    ********************<--|------- This is the HTML side (a rectangle with
|     ******************    |        rounded corners)
|                         <-|-- with transparent background that must
+---------------------------+   remain transparent for the desktop window
```

I searched about how can I set the transparent background for the webview and I found this code on all places:

```
QPalette pal = view->palette();
pal.setBrush(QPalette::Base, Qt::transparent);
view->page()->setPalette(pal);
view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, false);
```

The code above doesn't work properly. This is how my window does look:

> [image]
>
> So, the issue is that the gray part MUST be transparent. How can I solve this?

I use the following code to undecorate the window.

```
view->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me :

```
view->setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Comment: Yes, the next milestone will be to activate the window in the background if I click on the transparent area. :-)

Comment: @Johnツ Yeah, I will check that tomorrow.

Comment: What about QPalette? it throws `QPalette has no attribute setStyleSheet`?