# How to trigger a click on known coordinates of the screen?

Tags: qt, eventtrigger, qt5.1

Consider I have two windows: `window1` and `window2` like below

```
------------------------------
| x | This is the window1    |
|----------------------------|
|                            |
|    This window contains    |
|   a webview that has       |
|   transparent background. -|----------------|
|           | x |            | This is window2|
|            - - - - - - - --|----------------|
|           |If I click HERE |                |
------------------------------                |
            | I want to activate window2.     |
            |                                 |
            |                                 |
            |                                 |
            -----------------------------------
```

`window1` loads a HTML file into a `QWebView` and there is a transparent area [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19549975/1420197).

Now the problem is that when I click on the transparent area the window that is under the `window1` (in this case `window2`) is **not activated**. That's normal, because there is a HTML document with a transparent background.

I think that the correct way would be to make a function in C++ that would simulate *a click on known coordinates **under** the activated window*.

How can I do this in Qt?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can reimplement the virtual QWidget function:

```
void QWidget::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
```

And specify the "clickable rectangle" :

```
void MyWebView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event ) {
   // Set this a class variable
   QRect clickableArea = QRect( int x, int y, int width, int height);
   if( clickableArea->contains(event->pos()) ) {
       // Activate window2
   }
}
```

Comment: Not only activate - what if the window2 contains a button? If the user clicks on the transparent background the button has to be clicked...